# How to create merge request to master after merging to a particular branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm having a bit odd workflow, where I first accept merge request to a *release* branch, and afterwards I'm creating merge request to merge *release* branch into *master*.

Is there a way to automatically create a single merge request if there are (multiple) requestest being merged into *release* branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way as of today is that you create a [webhook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html) for that, and use https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#create-mr and https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#accept-mr API endpoints to automatise it.

Of course this will need to be implemented by you, but it is certainly possible.

Comment: As I understang, I have to deliver an api to receive a hook info and create a merge request hitting gitlab back. So there is no built in trick to do this without delivering additional service, am I right?

Comment: @yergo There is no other way.

Comment: Ok, please, insclude this in your answer and I'll can accept this at that point. Thank you!